# Can you turn Leaflet EasyButton off automatically on 'mouseup'?

Tags: javascript, button, leaflet

I would like to have the user be able to turn on a state changing EasyButton, select an area on the map (by holding down the shift key and dragging the mouse), and then once the mouse is released, have the easy button turned off automatically. Right now, you turn the easybutton on, select an area which gives you Lat/Long for a bounding box. Works great. BUT, when you click to turn the EasyButton off, it overrides your selection (assigns new coordinates to the area you clicked where the EasyButton is). My code:

```
    var stateChangingButton = L.easyButton({
            states: [{
                    stateName: 'ButtonOff',      
                    icon:      'X',               
                    title:     'Turn Button On', 
                    onClick: function(btn, map) {    
                            btn.button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                            btn.state('ButtonOn');
                            map.on('mousedown', getClickLocation);
                            map.on('mouseup', getReleaseLocation);
                            map.on('mouseup', toGeoJsonBounds);
                            map.on('mouseup', addSelectionLayer);
                            map.on('mouseup', addColorSelection);                                
                    }
                }, {
                    stateName: 'ButtonOn',
                    icon:      'X',
                    title:     'Turn Button Off',
                    onClick: function(btn, map) {
                        btn.state('ButtonOff');
                            btn.state('ButtonOff');
                            btn.button.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                            map.off('mousedown', getClickLocation);
                            map.off('mouseup', getReleaseLocation);
                            map.off('mouseup', toGeoJsonBounds);
                            map.off('mouseup', addSelectionLayer);
                            map.off('mouseup', addColorSelection);                             

                    }
                    }]
                });

                stateChangingButton.addTo(map);
```

I have tried this in a desperate attempt and it gives an error:

```
       //map.on('mouseup', btn.state('ButtonOff'));
```

I have tried creating a function and it says btn is undefined:

```
        function buttonAutoOff(){
            btn.state('ButtonOff');
         }
```

I'm new to JavaScript and Leaflet and I have to do this for my job. Is what I'm asking even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "boxzoomend" event.

```
map.on('boxzoomend', function(){
  stateChangingButton.state('ButtonOff');
  stateChangingButton.button.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});
```

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/andrea689/y0xpmpm0/

Comment: your example does not work. I also have fallen into the same issue. is there any suggestion from you? thanks

Comment: I just tried it and it works. Try to click the button below the zoom buttons and it will turn red, then zoom in a map area by pressing the shift key and you will see that the button will return to white.

Comment: thank you. I tried with map.on('click', function(){}); and it worked